# How does offering asylum not violate the prime directive?

Tags: star-trek

Assuming that the criteria by which the offer of asylum is offered is based on human values, how can it be offered without violating the prime directive?

Comment: Not sure, but I think the idea is that the person is being removed from their society.  Their disappearance might have some effect, but ultimately the native culture remains "untainted" by Federation culture at large.

Comment: Can you cite a specific instance where you think it might have done so?

Comment: yes we need specifics for this, they typically wouldn't be interacting with a planet in which offering asylum to somebody would infringe on the prime directive. plus its not human values anymore, it would be a set of values the entire federation holds by.

Comment: Don't most of the interactions with aliens in Star Trek end up violating the Prime Directive? As far as the writers are concerned, that rule was made to be broken.

Comment: @KSmarts not at all. As originally written, the Prime Directive only applied to planets that were not already warp-capable. The idea was not to tell them there were other worlds or sentient life until they has started to discover those things for themselves. Depending on plot, the meaning has been occasionally expanded, but IMO once a planet was part of the Federation, the Prime Directive becomes irrelevant.

Comment: Generally, asylum is requested by an individual. For example, I, as a member of a non warp capable species, would have to find myself in contact with a warp capable species (the Federation) and request asylum. Presumably, some other violation of the Prime Directive might have already occurred and someone on their crew may have made me aware of the fact that asylum is an option but I would still have to ask for it from them.

Comment: Broadly, asylum will mean removing the refugees from the situation.

Even if that changes the status quo by removing one army from the war, that's wholly different to giving that same side better armour…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Prime Directive (also known as the most routinely violated capital law in history) forbids the interference in the overall development of a non-warp-capable culture. I think it's been defined differently in different series, but the first time we get a real description of it, in the original series, it is given as:

> "No identification of self or mission. No interference with the social development of said planet. No references to space or the fact that there are other worlds or civilizations."

Note that the reference is to the social development of *the planet*. Actions which affect a single individual, which cannot subsequently impact the planet as a whole, would appear to be legal under the prime directive.

Furthermore, according to the Star Trek Technical Manual, there are exceptions:

> But this principle shall not prejudice the application of enforcement measures under Chapter VII.

This would imply that there were recognized legal situations where the Prime Directive can legally be ignored in the cause of justice. Someone in need of asylum may fall into this exemption.

Comment: There must also be exceptions when a low-tech society has already been contacted by some *other* warp-capable society.

Comment: Nice answer, but if that is the case, it's not really the "prime" directive. The word "prime" implies it can't be trumped.

Comment: probably. I think the general idea is "if they don't already know about aliens, you're not allowed to tell them, and you're not allowed to hurry them along."

Comment: @pingu Prime just implies that's it's first (primary) or most important, not immutable, inviolate, or inflexible. It's also separate from the *mission*, such as Enterprise's:  To explore strange new worlds, to seek out new life and new civilizations, to boldly go where no one has gone before.